# Append Files in Input Type File with Multiple Before Uploading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, forms

I have a form on my laravel website with a section that allows users to upload multiple image files (with a preview of the selected images). If a user only chooses multiple images once, everything works, and the selected images get uploaded. However, if a user selects multiple images on two separate occasions before submitting the form, only the last bunch of selected images will be uploaded.

For example; a user selects 4 images, then they fill out some other fields on the form, and then they decide to add 3 more images on top of the 4 images they previously selected before submitting the form. The image preview box will contain all 7 images they have selected, but once they submit the form, only the last 3 images they selected will be uploaded.

HTML Multiple File Input:

```
<input id="gphotos" type="file" name="gphotos[]" multiple>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function gphoto(input, ImagePreview) {
    if (input.files) {
        var fileAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < fileAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.preview').css('margin-top', '4px');
                $($.parseHTML('<img class="gphoto">')).attr('src', e.target.result).appendTo(ImagePreview);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
};

$('#gphotos').change(function() {
    gphoto(this, 'div.preview');
});
```

Controller:

```
if (request('gphotos')) {
        $imageArray['gphotos'] = array();

        foreach (request()->gphotos as $gphoto) {
            $gphotoPath = $gphoto->store('gphotos', 'public');

            $imageArray['gphotos'][] =  $gphotoPath;
        }

        $imageArray['gphotos'] = json_encode($imageArray['gphotos']);
    }
```

I would like users to be able to select multiple images on multiple separate occasions before submitting the form, and all their images being uploaded. I have tried searching all over the internet, but no one has a simple solution to this seemingly simple problem. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me solve this issue.

Comment: How do you submit your files. Is it through AJAX or without JavaScript?

Comment: Without JavaScript

Comment: Well, this case calls for JavaScript as you're changing the default behavior of a form. You'll need to store your uploaded images in a container to collect them. And when you submit them, send the container through AJAX instead of actually sending the form. This way **you** control what is being sent.

Comment: Can you give me a code example on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Multiple File Input:

```
<input id="gphotos" type="file" name="gphotos[]" multiple>
<div class="store"></div>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function gphoto(input, ImagePreview) {
        var files = input.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);

        filesArr.forEach(function(f) {
            if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
                return;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.preview').css('margin-top', '4px');
                $($.parseHTML('<img class="gphoto">')).attr('src', e.target.result).appendTo(ImagePreview);
                $($.parseHTML('<input type="hidden" name="photos[]">')).attr('value', e.target.result).appendTo($('.store'));
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        });
    }

    $('#gphotos').change(function() {
        gphoto(this, 'div.preview');
    });
```

Controller:

```
if (request('photos')) {
            $imageArray['gphotos'] = array();

            foreach (request()->photos as $gphoto) {
                $base64_str = substr($gphoto, strpos($gphoto, ",")+1);
                $gphotoPath = 'gphotos/'.\Str::random(11) . '.jpg';
                $gphoto = base64_decode($base64_str);
                \Storage::disk('public')->put($gphotoPath, $gphoto);

               $imageArray['gphotos'][] =  $gphotoPath;
            }

            $imageArray['gphotos'] = json_encode($imageArray['gphotos']);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the form handle it's own submission, create your own. Listen for the `submit` event on the form and whenever you submit, cancel the default behavior and send your data with AJAX. In this case the jQuery [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. Send it to a PHP file which handles your incoming request.

You can store files, like images, in a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. It's a container to set key / value pairs to send with an HTTP request. So create one.

In your `change` event listener you'll want to add each selected image to this `FormData` container so that the images will be stored there. This way you can select new images every time and add them to the container. And when you submit you only submit that container with the images in them.

Then when images are uploaded successfully loop through the container and delete each key in it so the user can restart the whole process.

```
<form id="gphotos-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="gphotos" type="file" name="gphotos[]" multiple>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
// Container for the images.
const selectedImages = new FormData();

function gphoto(input, imagePreview) {
  for (const file of input.files) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.classList.add('gphoto');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    image.onload = event => {
      $(imagePreview).append(image);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(event.target.src);
    };

    // Image is added here.
    selectedImages.append('gphotos', file);

  }
}

$('#gphotos').on('change', function() {
  gphoto(this, 'div.preview');
});

$('#gphotos-form').on('submit', function(event) {

  // Get the data from the form, but remove the gphotos[] one,
  // because we want to use our own collection of images.
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  formData.delete('gphotos[]');
  for (const file of selectedImages.values()) {
    formData.append('gphotos', file);
  }

  // Send container to your server.
  // Change the url: value to your PHP script.
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);

      // Delete all the images from the container.
      for (let key of selectedImages.keys()) {
        selectedImages.delete(key)
      });

      // Clear the preview.
      $('div.preview').html('');

    }
  });

  event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Will this submit other form data as well? The form also has other single image fields and text fields.

Comment: Thank you for your answer by the way. I will still try this method while I am waiting for your response.

Comment: Well, no it doesn't. But you can by creating another `FormData` object in the submit event and combine the two. I'll add it to the example.

Comment: Can this be done without AJAX or FormData()? Is there a way we can append the selected images to FileReader() instead?

Comment: I'm afraid not. `FileReader` is meant to read the file and use it in your document, but does not provide a way to send files. `FormData` on the other hand is meant for the purpose of collecting data and send it in one package to the server. The problem lies in that you can't add the new files to the old files in the **same** `<input type="file">`. However, that maybe dynamically adding a new input after every upload would be a workaround. I'll try something.

Comment: I tried this method, but I can't get it to save the images to the mysql database. Can I try using axios?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how that will be any different.

Comment: I don't know either, I am just trying to come up with ideas. I used axios on a different form for my website, so that's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new `<input type="file">` whenever you finished uploading the previous files and hide the previous input. This way you keep adding a new input every time you want to add more files and prevent the previous input from being overwritten.

And it doesn't require you to use AJAX.

```
<form id="gphotos-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="gphotos-upload">
    <input class="gphotos" type="file" name="gphotos[]" multiple>
  </div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
.ghpotos[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```
let $uploads = $('.gphotos-upload');
let $preview = $('div.preview');

$('#gphotos-form').on('change', function(event) {

  let $currentInput = $(event.target);
  let $newInput = $('<input class="gphotos" type="file" name="gphotos[]" multiple>');

  for (const file of event.target.files) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.classList.add('gphoto');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    image.onload = event => {
      $preview.append(image);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(event.target.src);
    };
  }

  // Disabled and hide current input.
  $currentInput.attr('hidden', '');

  // Add new input to do another upload.
  $uploads.append($newInput);

});
```

Comment: Now the image preview doesn't work and it doesn't append a new input

Comment: Make sure your HTML is the same as in the example here.

Comment: Yes, I made sure it was

Comment: Ah, I see. I've made a typo in the preview div selector. And I removed the `disabled` attribute on the used inputs so that they will be sent to the server. Try it again.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: hidden is not defined

Comment: I changed $currentInput.attr(hidden, ''); to $currentInput.hide(); and now there are no errors, but when I try to add a second batch of imgaes, nothing happens.

Comment: Sometimes you have a day when typo's are abundant ;). The `hidden` word had to be a string. But what do you mean with *nothing happens*. Are there no images displayed? Or does the submit nog send any files?

Comment: It’s okay, I have those days quite often as well, but no images are displayed and it still only submits the last image I select

Comment: Could you make a codepen, or other service, snippet in which I can see the code working. I've tried it out myself and it seems to work.